# Routh-Hurwitz criterion for systems with delay

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Is there an analogue of [Routh-Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) for 
systems with time-delay?

In other words, given the open-loop transfer function

$$G(s) = e^{-sT} \frac{P(s)}{Q(s)}$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials, it is possible to decide if the closed-loop transfer function $G/(1+G)$ is stable or not in terms of $T$ and the coefficients of $Q$?

Comment: Normally, the component of time delay $e^{-sT}$, which is a irrational function is converted to a rational function using a Pade approximant. As an example, $e^{-sT} \approx \frac{1 - \frac{sT}{2}}{1+\frac{sT}{s}}$. Then the poles can be analyzed using the Routh-Hurwitz criterion.

Comment: @WinterSoldier Do you know if there is a lower bound for the order of Padé approximant such that the approximate rational transfer function is guaranteed to be stable if and only if the original transfer function $G(s)$ is stable?

Comment: To my knowledge, I am not sure if a lower bound for a given order exists. However, note that the Padé approximant is usually chosen - no matter the degree - so that all poles (of the approximant) lie in the left half s-plane. Therefore, the Padé approximant only affects the stability (or instability) of the system if $G(s)$ is the loop transfer function and not the closed loop transfer function.

Comment: @WinterSoldier Thanks, I see your point now. I should have added in the question that $G(s)$ is the open loop transfer function and that I wish to analyze the (BIBO) stability of the closed-loop function $G(s)/(1+G(s))$. If $G(s)=e^{-st}\frac{P(s)}{Q(s)}$ is already the closed loop function, then $G$ is stable iff $Q$ is Hurwitz, right?

Comment: Let's assume that the closed loop transfer function is $\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)H(s)}$, where $G(s)$ is the forward transfer function, and $G(s)H(s)$ is the loop transfer function - where $H(s)$ is the feedback gain. Then you want to perform stability analysis on the characteristic equation which is $1+G(s)H(s)$. If we assume unity feedback [$H(s)=1$], then you want to perform stability analysis on $1+G(s)$ and not $G(s)$. In this case, you can use a first or higher order Padé approximant for $e^{-sT}$ and then perform an approximate stability analysis using Routh-Hurwitz.

Comment: To be clear, you want to perform an approximate stability analysis using the Routh-Hurwitz on $1 + e^{-sT}{\frac{P(s)}{Q(s)}} = 0$.
Using (as an example) a first order Pade approximation, the characteristic equation becomes $(1 + \frac{sT}{2})Q(s) + (1 - \frac{sT}{2})P(s) = 0$.
If it is stable by Routh-Hurwitz, then it is approximately stable, since an approximation was used.

Comment: @WinterSoldier Thanks. Do you know if there is also an exact method (at least for some classes of systems) ?

Comment: You can always use the [Nyquist criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion#The_Nyquist_criterion).